# Why is my Python code for DNA pattern not giving the right output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I input "ATACTCGTCGTCGATCGATACTCGTCTGTCGTCGAGTCGTTCGTCTCGTC" as the dna, and "TCGTC" as the pattern, it should output

____ * __ * _____________ * ______ * ___________ * ____ * ____ where it marks a star at the start position of the overlapping pattern.

[image]

But my code is not giving me the correct output, why?

Here's my code:

```
def printMatch(dna,pattern):
    for i in range(0,len(dna)):
      if dna[i:len(pattern)]!=pattern:
        dna+="_"
      else:
        dna+="*"
    print(dna)

def main():
    dna=input()
    pattern=input()
    printMatch(dna,pattern)

main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here: `dna[i:len(pattern)]`. The value after the `:` is the ending index, not the length of the substring. Do this instead: `dna[i:i+len(pattern)]`.

Comment: Even better: `dna.startswith(pattern, i)`